# Files read by lines sort average Python 3

Tags: python, performance, file, line

I have an input file:(last name, first name, class, score)

> ```
> John Smith 11 30
> Anna White  9 49
> Kate Balon  10 91
> Кузьмин Александр 11 99
> ```

I need to group the values based on class and get average

```
49.0 91.0 64.5
```

The code should read the lines  one by one, my code is working but it's too slow, how can I improve it?

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

import numpy

total = defaultdict(list)
with open('input', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for row in f:
        _class, range = map(float, row.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:])
        total[_class].append(range)


print(*(numpy.mean(v) for k, v in sorted(total.items(), key=itemgetter(0))))
```

Comment: you smell it right, i can't make the code faster

Comment: @L.Bond how big is your file?

Comment: from 3 to 200 lines

Comment: What is your definition of "slow" and "faster". There is not much you can do to make it significatly faster in pure Python. You can use pandas, but it will read the entire file.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious - though lots of things *might* make a difference:you're `float`ing the class number as well as the score; you're pushing to a dict of lists, then iterating over that - maybe a list of tuples might be faster (with different logic?)

Comment: @ Eli Korvigo the speed limit on the learning platform is 1000 ms, based on the description of the task i need to read the file line by line

Comment: Do you know how many classes there can be in advance (e.g. [1, 2, ..., 11]).

Comment: @EliKorvigo i assume there should be 3 (9,10,11) but i can't see all the test input files (just an assumption)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, there is not much you can do in pure Python to make this faster. I've got several minor optimisations. The first one (`alt1`) doesn't cast the group identifier string into float (which is an expensive operation). The second one (`alt2`) uses a standard dictionary with predefined groups. The third one (`alt3`) uses a list instead of a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
import random
from io import StringIO 
import numpy as np

# random data for benchmarks 
data = '\n'.join('first last {} {}'.format(random.randrange(1, 12), random.random()) for _ in range(1000))

def base(handle):
    # This is your implementation
    total = defaultdict(list)
    for row in handle:
        _class, range = map(float, row.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:])
        total[_class].append(range)
    return [np.mean(v) for k, v in sorted(total.items(), key=itemgetter(0))]

def alt1(handle):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for row in handle:
        group, value = row.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:]
        groups[group].append(float(value))
    return [np.mean(v) for k, v in sorted(groups.items(), key=itemgetter(0))]

def alt2(handle):
    groups = {str(i): [] for i in range(1, 12)}
    for row in handle:
        key, val = row.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:]
        groups[key].append(float(val))
    return [np.mean(group) for _, group in sorted(groups.items(), key=itemgetter(0))]

def alt3(handle):
    groups = [[] for _ in range(11)]
    for row in handle:
        key, val = row.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:]
        groups[int(key)-1].append(float(val))
    return [np.mean(group) for group in groups if group]
```

I can think of no other significant optimisations. Let's look at some benchmarks:

```
In [2]: %timeit base(StringIO(data))
1.18 ms ± 36.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit alt1(StringIO(data))
937 µs ± 30.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit alt2(StringIO(data))
941 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit alt3(StringIO(data))
1.08 ms ± 40.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

All three alternatives are faster than the original implementation. `alt1` and `alt2` have identical performance and are significantly faster. You might want to give them a shot.